# Glassfish 4 Admin cannot run on NetBeans 8.0

Tags: glassfish-4, netbeans-platform

I have installed **JDK 8.0** and installed **NetBeans IDE 8.0**. I can start the embedded GlassFish Server 4.0. But I cannot enter Glassfish Domain Admin Console.
I get the following messages ...

****Warning:   Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /**

**Severe:   PWC6117: File "C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\lib\install\applications__admingui\common\index.jsp" not found****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I can see Glassfish Domain Admin Console by changing **java.policy**.

**java.policy** is under **JAVA_HOME/jre8/lib/security**

My java.policy is like this ...

```
// Standard extensions get all permissions by default


**grant  {
        permission java.net.Socket.Permission "localhost:1527","listen";
};**

// default permissions granted to all domains

grant {
        // Allows any thread to stop itself using the java.lang.Thread.stop()
        // method that takes no argument.
        // Note that this permission is granted by default only to remain
        // backwards compatible.
        // It is strongly recommended that you either remove this permission
        // from this policy file or further restrict it to code sources
        // that you specify, because Thread.stop() is potentially unsafe.
        // See the API specification of java.lang.Thread.stop() for more
        // information.
        permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";

        // allows anyone to listen on dynamic ports
        permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:0", "listen";

        // "standard" properies that can be read by anyone

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.separator", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "path.separator", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "line.separator", "read";

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.name", "read";

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.name", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.name", "read";
};
```

Comment: This is what finally caused my admin GUI to show up!